# Sending multiple files in Postman - NodeJS

Tags: json, postman

I have a JSON request in the following structure-

```
{
    "user_id" : "1",
    "user_details" : {
      "name" : "my_name"
      "passport_image" : "passport_image.jpg"
     },
     "user_documents" : [
        {"file" : "doc_1.jpg"},
        {"file" : "doc_2.jpg"}
     ]       
}
```

How can I send files via postman that are part of a JSON request?

This is what I tried - 
[image]

But then `passport_image.jpg` would be its own field and not part of `user_details` object, correct?

And what about the array of `file` objects under `user_documents`? How can I send it too in the request?

I would appreciate help as I'm quite new to using `form-data` requests rather than `raw JSON` ones.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the keys as array. It can be set like this. `user_documents[0]` and the respective file for it.

[image]

This will work!

Comment: doesn't work for me, and why should it, the key name is the equivalent of the name string in an input form

Answer (score 2):

Actually I find solution on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LD7zMnJhyHw). You can choose multiple files by keeping <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and choose multiple files.[image]

Answer (score 0):

The above answer is wrong, the way to do it is to select the key value = to the value you used in your code, for instance see below:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function(req,file,cb) {
        cb(null,'uploads/')
    },
    filename: function(res,file,cb) {
        console.log('file= ',file)
        const uniqueSuffix=Date.now()+'-'+Math.round(Math.random()*1e9)
        cb(null, file.fieldname+'-'+uniqueSuffix+'.jpg')
    }
})
const upload = multer({storage:storage})

app.post('/uploads', upload.array('files',12), (req,res)=> 
{
    req.files.map((file)=>{
        console.log('received request: ', file)
    })
    res.status(200).send('received files')
})
```

Then in postman you just select several files, in this case less than 12 after clicking on the select files button. Just one entrance for multiple files.